# can WSP file deploy using create web setup of ASP.net project.?

Tags: installation

Is there any way to create web setup for deploy WSP file directly, when install a setup?

Means, I directly create **exe** file that manage all the things like register assembly or deploy wsp file to sharepoint site

Answer (score 3):

There is Codeplex solution [SharePoint Solution Installer](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/). This solution support to 2010 & 2013 versions as well.